# Cannot find file or its type declaration error in vercel deployment

Tags: next.js

I have a nextjs app, using tailwind css, typescript and shacn ui.
My tsconfig.json file -

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "typeRoots":  ["./types", "./node_modules/@types"],
    "incremental": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

My Component file -

```js
import { Metadata } from "next";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Icons } from "@/components/ui/Icons";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/Input";
import { buttonVariants } from "@/components/ui/Button";
import { validate } from "@/lib/validate";
import { toast } from "../ui/use-toast";
import { Label } from "../ui/Label";
```

these are the imports in my component.

Folder Structure -
[image]

When I am trying to build the app on the local machine, it works fine and the build is generated. but when I deploy it on vercel it give this error
Type error: Cannot find module '@/components/ui/Icons' or its corresponding type declarations.